# Chrome can't open localhost:3000 BrowserSync

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, browser-sync

Google Chrome never seems to be able to display http://localhost:3000 when starting up a server with BrowserSync

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
 mix.browserSync('locahost:8000');
```

But even using the 8000 does not work in Chrome. Firefox seems to be able to work with either.

Comment: add port in 8000 in mix.browserSync('locahost:8000');

Comment: still not working